# Changing Variables In Summation

Tags: recurrence-relations, change-of-variable

[image]

Isn't the change in the summation variables as intended by the author([Jeff Erickson](http://www.cs.illinois.edu/~jeffe)) wrongly done??

As far as I understood that change in summation variables limits is alike the way we do in Integral Calculus..

If  **i** is $0$ then **j** should be $ \lg n $

And

if **i** is $ \lg n $ then **j** should be $1$..

Could someone just explain me how is the **variable being interchanged** if I have

misunderstood the concept??

Thanks in Advance!!(Sorry for bad formatting)

Comment: Yes, wrongly done by author.

Comment: what's $\operatorname{lg}n$? and \operatorname{lg} to make it better

Answer (score 1):

I think the limit should be from $j=\log n$ to $j=1$.